# File paths in Python in the form of string throw errors

Tags: python, string, error-handling, filepath

I need to put a lot of filepaths in the form of strings in Python as part of my program. For example one of my directories is `D:\ful_automate\dl`. But Python recognizes some of the characters together as other characters and throws an error. In the example the error is `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'D:\x0cul_automate\\dl`. It happens a lot for me and every time I need to change the directory name to one that may not be problematic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `\` character is used to form character escapes; `\f` has special meaning.

Use `/` or use raw string `r''` instead.  Alternatively, you could ensure that Python reads the backslash as a backslash by escaping it with an additional `\`.

```
r'D:\ful_automate\dl'
'D:\\ful_automate\\dl'
'D:/ful_automate/dl'
```

Demo to show the difference:

```
>>> 'D:\ful_automate\dl'
'D:\x0cul_automate\\dl'
>>> r'D:\ful_automate\dl'
'D:\\ful_automate\\dl'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use raw string instead of string ie
    use r'filepath'
It fixes the problem off  blacklash "\"